# datatable only working for the first time

Tags: datatables

```
 function SearchUser(url, pageIndex) {

        var table;

            table = $('#UsersTable').DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                retrieve:true,
                ajax: {
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { username: $('#Username').val(), email: $('#Email').val(), companyID: $('#LifeCompanies').val(), page: pageIndex, isLocked: $('#Locked').is(':checked') }
                },
                columns: [
                    { "data": "UserId" },
                    { "data": "Username" },
                    { "data": "Email" },
                    { "data": "IsLockedOut" },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<span>wahoo</span>';
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
               }

<div id="search">
    <h3>Search:</h3>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Search","Admin"))
   {
        <div>

            <table width="500px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("Username")</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("Email")</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Locked:</td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBox("Locked")</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div id="searchForm">
                                @Html.Partial("SearchBuild")
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Search" onclick="SearchUser('/UserManagement/admin/Search',0)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Hi the code above uses the datatables jquery plugin.

It seems to only work for the first time I use that function.  The second time, it appears to hit the javascript but doesn't ever retrive any data from my mvc controller.

However if I use destroy instead of retrieve it works perfectly fine.

If I don't use retrieve or destroy, I get the "can't reinitialise table" error.

That function is just called by a button I click.

[image]

Comment: show your `document.ready` code as well

Comment: How are you calling function `SearchUser` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code to initialize your table and reload it separately.

Also it's not possible to modify initialization options via API unless you destroy and recreate the table.

You need another way to pass `pageIndex` variable. For example, you can create a hidden input with id `PageIndex` and set and retrieve value from there.

For example:

```
function initTable(url) {
    var table;

    table = $('#UsersTable').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        retrieve:true,
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
                username: $('#Username').val(), 
                email: $('#Email').val(), 
                companyID: $('#LifeCompanies').val(), 
                page: $('#PageIndex').val(), 
                isLocked: $('#Locked').is(':checked') 
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "UserId" },
            { "data": "Username" },
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "IsLockedOut" },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<span>wahoo</span>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

To search again you just need to call [`$('#UsersTable').DataTable().ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) API method.

If URL will change between searches use [`$('#UsersTable').DataTable().ajax.url(newurl).load()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()) API method instead.